# Conditionals on a chained deferred in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chaining, deferred

Let say I chained the `$.Deferred` like this.

```
$.each(data, function(k, v) {
    promise.then(function() {
        return $.post(...);
    }).then(function(data) {
        if(data)... // here is the conditions
        return $.post(...);
    }).then(function(data) {
        if(data)... // here is another condition
        return $.post(...);
    })
});

promise.done(function() {
    console.log("All Done!");
});
```

Am I doing it right? how do I prevent the next chain to execute if the condition return false, and where do I do this:

```
if(data){
   console.log('Success');
}
```

Can that code be in between those `.then`s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Joey, whether or not you are doing it right depends on the detail of what you are trying to achieve.

If you are trying to build one long `.then()` chain with a terminal `.done()`, where each `.then()`'s 'done' handler either :

- calls an asynchronous process, or
- **transparently passes data on to the next `.then()` in the chain**

*then*, the code should be of the following form :

```
var promise = ...;//An expression that returns a resolved or resolvable promise, to get the chain started.

$.each(data, function(k, v) {
    promise = promise.then(function() {//The `.then()` chain is built by assignment 
        if(data...) { return $.post(...); }
        else { return data; }//Transparent pass-through of `data`
    }).then(function(data) {
        if(data...) { return $.post(...); }
        else { return data; }//Transparent pass-through of `data`
    });
});

promise.done(function() {
    console.log("All Done!");
}).fail(function(jqXHR) {
    console.log("Incomplete - an ajax call failed");
});
```

If, however, you are trying to do the same but where each `.then()`'s 'done' handler either :

- calls an asynchronous process, or
- **interrupts the `.then()` chain**

*then*, the code should be of the following form :

```
var promise = ...;//An expression that returns a resolved or resolvable promise, to get the chain started.

$.each(data, function(k, v) {
    promise = promise.then(function(data) {
        if(data...) { return $.post(...); }
        else { return $.Deferred().reject(data).promise(); }//Force the chain to be interrupted
    }).then(function(data) {
        if(data...) { return $.post(...); }
        else { return $.Deferred().reject(data).promise(); }//Force the chain to be interrupted
    });
});

promise.done(function() {
    console.log("All Done!");
}).fail(function(obj) {//Note: `obj` may be a data object or an jqXHR object depending on what caused rejection.
    console.log("Incomplete - an ajax call failed or returned data determined that the then() chain should be interrupted");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery's `then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) returns a new promise, which is monitored by the following chained `then`. Whatever is returned from the previous `then` is passed as the first argument of the next `then`.

```
promise.then(function() {
  return $.post(...);
}).then(function(data) {
  //we return false or some indicator that next shouldn't run
  if(!data) return false; 
  //else we return something
  else return $.post(...);
}).then(function(data) {
  //here we receive false, we return early, preventing further code from executing
  if(!data) return false;
  //otherwise, the following code runs
  return $.post(...);
})
```

Comment: will i able to log, before returning false?

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito where is that `if(data)` situated?

Comment: in all conditions, for example if the first then returns false, i would like to `console.log()` each status of the chain...

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito just so you know, returning `$.post` returns a deferred. All your `then` checks for `data` which will always be true since you return a deferred object on all `then`s.

Comment: hmm,,okay, i'll just try things out.